# SQL: sum up two columns from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables with same column name and I want to sum up all the value from two different table with column name TotalIncome not by ID.

Basically, I would like to take this two tables

## tblRespondent

Respondent'sID Name TotalIncome

```
 1         John   40.00
 2         Carl   50.00
```

### tblRespondent'sMember

Respondent'sID Name  TotalIncome

```
 1         Wendy   30.00
 1         Ged     10.00
 2         Paolo   15.00
```

But the output I want for total income is 145.00

PS: my english is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using two subqueries, one for the sum from each table.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(TotalIncome) FROM tblRespondent) +
       (SELECT SUM(TotalIncome) FROM tblRespondentsMember) AS total_income
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table, then `sum()` the TotalIncome values.

```
select sum(TotalIncome)
from
(
    select TotalIncome from tblRespondent
    UNION ALL
    select TotalIncome from tblRespondentsMember
) dt
```

ANSI SQL compliant answer - i.e. will work with almost any dbms!

Comment: My edit: Select `TotalIncome` from both sides of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my sample query for your desired output. 
Please let me know if it helps you. I have used with clause to test the data.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT 'John' Name,40.00  AMount FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Carl' Name,50.00 AMount FROM dual
), T2 AS
(
SELECT 'Wendy' Name,30.00  AMount FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Ged' Name,10.00  AMount FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Paolo' Name,15.00  AMount FROM dual 
)
SELECT Sum(AMount) FROM(
SELECT AMount FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT AMount FROM T2);
```